# Order results by value

Tags: c++

I want to loop through a vector to find records with a given ID.  The ID is provided by the user.  The code below will return all values with the given ID in the order they appear in the vector.  How can I order the results by Price, say from lowest to highest?

```
   for(Seek = List.begin() ; Seek !=List.end() ; Seek++) {
    if(Seek->GetID() == Input)
        cout <<"Price: " << Seek->GetPrice() << endl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the C++ Standard Library sort function with a custom compare should do what you want. I don't know what type *Seek* is exactly but here is something to get you started.

```
struct compareSeeks {
  bool operator() (const Seek& lhs, const Seek& rhs) { return (lhs.price < rhs.price);}
} mycompare;

// method code here...
sort(List.begin(); List.end(), mycompare);
```

You can see more here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/.

[update] I assume that your list is already filtered on the correct ID and so I am focusing on just the sort aspect of the problem.

Comment: A free function that takes two const references should suffice. No need to whip out a struct just to compare two objects.

Comment: I thought the STL sort function required an object with a the operator() overloaded. Could you point to an example that shows otherwise? I have always used the struct/class to build my comparators but I know there are often many ways to do things in C++.

Comment: The standard library (please don't say "STL"; that is long dead) sort function is templated, and as such requires any type T such that the expression `T(a, b)` (where `a` and `b` are const references to container elements) is valid. This is what we call "ad-hoc polymorphism". In any case, please do pay attention to const correctness.

Comment: @Etienne, a free function will take the same three lines of code, with minimal different content. But a free function will have worse performance usually...

Comment: @Karl: about the STL part, sorry old habits die hard. As far as const correctness goes, I wouldn't be so picky given the nature of the question and I would argue that it's near trivial in this case anyway.  Perhaps consider lighter phrasing next time as to not come off so critical.

Comment: @Andrew: sort requires a "function object". That can be an instance of a class with an overloaded operator(), a free function, or a static method (or a lambda expression in C++0x). As for an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecdecxh1.aspx

Comment: @Etienne: thanks for that clarification. My C++ gets rusty if I don't use it enough and that link had a good example. Though I wonder if I mentally blocked it at some point due to something related to Johannes' comment about performance. Either way, thx.